# Why the value of head.next is not null in the following code?

Tags: java, class, linked-list, new-operator

I have a confusion in the following code:-

The Node class:-

```
class Node
{
  int data;
  Node next;
  Node(int n)
  {
    data=n;
    next=null;
  }
}
```

The LinkedList class:-

```
class LinkedList
{
  Node head;
  void insertLinkedList(int n)
  {
    Node newNode=new Node(n);
    if(head==null)
    {
      head=newNode;
    }
    else
    {
      Node ptr=head;
      while(ptr.next!=null)
      {
        ptr=ptr.next;
      }
      ptr.next=newNode;
    }
  }
```

Initially, `head` is null. On `insertLinkedList(1)` function call the situation is:-

`newNode.data = 1`
`newNode.next = null`

`head.data = 1`
`head.next = null`

After the second function call `insertLinkedList(2)` the expected situation is:-

`newNode.data = 2`
`newNode.next = null`

`head.data = 2`
`head.next = null`

But the actual value of `head.next` is not null. Instead, it is storing the reference to the first node.

Can someone help me in getting a better understanding of this?

Comment: As you are inserting at the end of the list `head.next` should still reference to your first node (1), where `next` in turn will reference the second node (2). The second node will have `next` as null.

Comment: Why do you think it is expected to be null? It should point to the *second* node, which surely it does.

Comment: I was unaware as to how reference works. Now I have a clear understanding of references. As per my earlier knowledge I use to think the references as normal variables which creates a copy on assignment rather than pointing to the object, which created the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

After inserting second Node expected value of head.next is NOT NULL.

```
Node ptr=head;
```

Here ptr is use to refer the head node. So after first insertion

```
while(ptr.next!=null)
```

is false and it does not enter loop. After loop

```
ptr.next=newNode;
```

is executed. And it assigns head's next value as reference to the new Node. Hence head.next is not null; as expected.

Comment: I was unaware as to how reference works. Now I have a clear understanding of references. As per my earlier knowledge I use to think the references as normal variables which creates a copy on assignment rather than pointing to the object, which created the confusion.